# Tibco SSL communication says no trusted certificates are set

Tags: spring, weblogic12c, tibco-ems, jmstemplate

I am trying to establish a SSL communication with Tibco EMS. TCP communication is successful and I was able to publish a message. I ma configuring it with JMS template. Below are the properties I have for communicating with Tibco.

```
#Tibco EMS Setup
tibco.ems.namingUrl=ssl://machineName:7223


##Tibco User name/pwd  
java.naming.security.principal=testUser
java.naming.security.credentials=testUser


##Tibco Configuration details SSLQueueConnectionFactory
ems.connectionFactory=SSLQueueConnectionFactory
ems.queueName=queueName
ems.contextFactory=com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory
```

here is the code fro JMS template setup done in Spring.

```
public class JMSConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public JndiTemplate jndiTemplate() throws JMSException {
        JndiTemplate jndiTemplate = new JndiTemplate();
        Properties jndiProps = new Properties();
        Properties props = System.getProperties();



        jndiProps.setProperty("java.naming.security.principal", environment.getProperty("java.naming.security.principal"));
        jndiProps.setProperty("java.naming.security.credentials", environment.getProperty("java.naming.security.credentials"));
        jndiProps.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", environment.getProperty("ems.contextFactory"));
        jndiProps.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url", environment.getProperty("tibco.ems.namingUrl"));
        jndiProps.setProperty("com.tibco.tibjms.naming.security_protocol", "ssl");
        jndiProps.setProperty("com.tibco.tibjms.naming.ssl_enable_verify_host", "false");

        jndiTemplate.setEnvironment(jndiProps);
        return jndiTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter authenticate() throws JMSException, NamingException {
        UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter = new UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter(); 
        userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.setUsername(environment.getProperty("java.naming.security.principal"));
        userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.setPassword(environment.getProperty("java.naming.security.credentials"));
        userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.setTargetConnectionFactory(connectionFactoryProxy());
        return userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public JndiObjectFactoryBean jmsConnectionFactory() throws JMSException {
        JndiObjectFactoryBean jndiObjectFactoryBean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
        jndiObjectFactoryBean.setJndiTemplate(jndiTemplate());
        jndiObjectFactoryBean.setJndiName(environment.getProperty("ems.connectionFactory"));
        return jndiObjectFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public JndiObjectFactoryBean jmsQueueName() throws JMSException {
        JndiObjectFactoryBean jndiObjectFactoryBean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
        jndiObjectFactoryBean.setJndiTemplate(jndiTemplate());
        jndiObjectFactoryBean.setJndiName(environment.getProperty("ems.queueName")); 
        return jndiObjectFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public TransactionAwareConnectionFactoryProxy connectionFactoryProxy() throws NamingException, JMSException {
        return new TransactionAwareConnectionFactoryProxy((ConnectionFactory) jmsConnectionFactory().getObject());
    }

    @Bean(name="jmsTemplate")
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() throws JMSException, NamingException {
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(authenticate());
        jmsTemplate.setSessionTransacted(false);
        jmsTemplate.setReceiveTimeout(5000);
        jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestination((Destination) jmsQueueName().getObject());
        return jmsTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public QueueMessageSender queueMessageSender() {        
        return  new QueueMessageSender();
    }
```

I have read [this](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2420909?tstart=0) link and checked if the keys are present in server machine which is have .pem key and certificate in paths specified.
ssl_server_identity = machineName.crt.pem
ssl_server_key = machineName.key.pem

Here is the error I am getting when trying to publish an EMs message.

```
org.springframework.jms.JmsSecurityException: Can not initialize SSL client: no trusted certificates are set; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: Can not initialize SSL client: no trusted certificates are set
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:291)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:169)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:496)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:568)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:559)
    at com.project.name.jms.QueueMessageSender.postMessage(QueueMessageSender.java:32)
    at com.project.name.controller.ControllerClass.publishEMS(ControllerClass.java:228)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:751)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:243)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3432)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: Can not initialize SSL client: no trusted certificates are set
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxLinkSSL._initSSL(TibjmsxLinkSSL.java:281)
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxLinkSSL.connect(TibjmsxLinkSSL.java:383)
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsConnection._create(TibjmsConnection.java:1354)
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsConnection.<init>(TibjmsConnection.java:4320)
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsQueueConnection.<init>(TibjmsQueueConnection.java:39)
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxCFImpl._createImpl(TibjmsxCFImpl.java:200)
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxCFImpl._createConnection(TibjmsxCFImpl.java:253)
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsConnectionFactory.createConnection(TibjmsConnectionFactory.java:61)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.TransactionAwareConnectionFactoryProxy.createConnection(TransactionAwareConnectionFactoryProxy.java:147)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.doCreateConnection(UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.java:178)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.createConnection(UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.java:152)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:180)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:483)
```

Weblogic is the server. Should I set anything in weblogic for SSL communication?

Please suggest if I need to add additional parameters in weblogic server to establish a communication. Also, here are the tibco dependencies I'm using in POM.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.tibco</groupId>
    <artifactId>tibjms</artifactId>
    <version>8.1.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>tibco</groupId>
    <artifactId>tibcrypt</artifactId>
    <version>2.14.100</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: is this even a right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

By default, WebLogic has only demo certs available. If you need to enable SSL communication for a WebLogic server, [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24422/identity_trust.htm#SECMG369) and [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24422/ssl.htm#SECMG395)  are good places to start. You're going to have to add your certs to a JKS keystore file and point your WebLogic server at that file. Otherwise, WebLogic is only going to be presenting it's demo certificate to Tibco.

Comment: Brian, instead of doing it this way I have configured a foreign server in JMS module for WLS. strange! it connected to tibco and everything was smooth. But will def try setting the certificates and keystore and check on this. Thank you for getting back.